# Loading all Users who liked a Post

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am rebuilding Instagram and want to show all User who liked a post.
I am Running into a problem that my tableview doesn't show the users who liked the post.

For a like I will add it on firebase

```
                    self.REF_LIKES_POSTS.child(postId).child(uid).setValue(true)
```

Now I want to get all the users who liked the post in my UsersLikedViewController

```
  func loadUserLikes() {

    API.User.REF_POST_USERS_LIKED.observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in

        API.User.observeUserLikes(withPostId: snapshot.key, completion: {
            user in
            self.fetchUser(uid: user.id!, completed: {
                self.users.insert(user, at: 0)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        })
    })

}


func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {

    API.User.observeUser(withId: uid, completion: {
        user in
        self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
        completed()
    })

}
```

My User API

```
class UserApi {

var REF_USERS = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
var REF_POST_USERS_LIKED = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("LikesFromUsers")
var REF_POST = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")


func observeUser(withId uid: String,  completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {

    REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User.transformUserInfo(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(user)
        }
    })
}



func observeUsers(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    REF_USERS.observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User.transformUserInfo(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            if user.id! != API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid {
                completion(user)

            }
        }

    })
}


func observeUserLikes(withPostId id: String , completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    REF_POST_USERS_LIKED.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            let allUsers = User.transformUserInfo(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(allUsers)
        }
    })
}

}
```

My  function fetchUser() in LoadUserLikes returns nil, so there is something missing.
I only accomplished that there were all the already shared posts, so a user could follow and unfollow a post but that makes no sense haha.

thanks for your time

```
 "LikesFromUsers" : {
"-KjY30xwWA2IJBwlvyzf" : {
  "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : true
}
  },
  "comments" : {
"-KjTIBDeMsho70t-jnGw" : {
  "commentText" : "klasse Auto",
  "creationDate" : 1.494083221667957E9,
  "likeCount" : 0,
  "uid" : "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2"
},
"-Kjc-uvCSn7qz8VkDVCR" : {
  "commentText" : "toll",
  "creationDate" : 1.494246203366448E9,
  "likeCount" : 0,
  "uid" : "es5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3"
},
"-Kjc01pbWUtZn8XMlRGL" : {
  "commentText" : "fantatsico ",
  "creationDate" : 1.494246235776034E9,
  "likeCount" : 1,
  "likes" : {
    "es5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3" : true
  },
   }
  },

"posts" : {
"-KjTBFFE5QzktG1IT5u0" : {
  "bookmarkCount" : 0,
  "caption" : "Toll",
  "commentCount" : 1,
  "creationDate" : 1.494081403379004E9,
  "hoursSinceUpload" : 0,
  "likeCount" : 0,
  "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F76192CBE-55F0-4907-889A-849E196D5796?alt=media&token=de675609-4b73-411d-b402-f1ff3db64f79",
  "ratio" : 1.502732240437158,
  "score" : 16.38698994684219,
  "uid" : "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2"
},
"-KjTHFNe1RRS8Ly6bKsA" : {
  "bookmarkCount" : 1,
  "bookmarks" : {
    "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : true
  },
  "caption" : "Traumhaft",
  "commentCount" : 0,
  "creationDate" : 1.494082976550228E9,
  "hoursSinceUpload" : 0,
  "likeCount" : 2,
  "likes" : {
    "es5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3" : true,
    "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : true
  },
  "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F306BF7E1-9FEF-493A-ABF8-C0E061E8648F?alt=media&token=128bdd90-023a-49ac-8361-19c02c631183",
  "ratio" : 1.502732240437158,
  "score" : 166.6491847103437,
  "uid" : "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2"
},
"-KjY30xwWA2IJBwlvyzf" : {
  "bookmarkCount" : 1,
  "bookmarks" : {
    "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : true
  },
  "caption" : "Traumwagen",
  "commentCount" : 2,
  "creationDate" : 1.494163133228368E9,
  "hoursSinceUpload" : 0,
  "likeCount" : 2,
  "likes" : {
    "es5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3" : true,
    "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : true
  },
  "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F5C83FB24-BE21-49D9-863F-039FDE34969E?alt=media&token=e7e053a0-1966-4614-afad-42cab87f7880",
  "ratio" : 1.775,
  "score" : 280.0086305441856,
  "uid" : "jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2",
  "videoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F5951720B-54F4-44C1-859C-43D8ACB98334?alt=media&token=02be7eaf-4970-4059-b07d-036a4f182b28"
    }
  },


 "users" : {
"es5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3" : {
  "email" : "user3@mail.de",
  "profilText" : "Schreib etwas über dich",
  "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2Fes5fIbnKFpX4szcCbroUqHjJg6E3?alt=media&token=ce8d8722-39bc-457a-8149-e51c837ef0a3",
  "username" : "Blondine",
  "username_lowercase" : "blondine"
},
"jlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2" : {
  "email" : "user2@mail.de",
  "profilText" : "Schreib etwas über dich",
  "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2FjlkRoaucY6Q4GBkzhor5yAAl97I2?alt=media&token=197ee89d-c328-4d04-a56e-02a9450b1720",
  "username" : "Marie",
  "username_lowercase" : "marie"
},
"tH3714ywXTOgGK0cxBgGvTiSDLl2" : {
  "email" : "user1@mail.de",
  "profilText" : "Schreib etwas über dich",
  "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2FtH3714ywXTOgGK0cxBgGvTiSDLl2?alt=media&token=b08060a8-ef6b-4cf7-a73f-5bacd1ddada5",
  "username" : "Elena",
  "username_lowercase" : "elena"
}
  }
}
```

EDIT : MORE CODE

```
 class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var posts = [Post]()
var users = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 521
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadPost()



    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView?.refreshControl = refreshControl




}

func handleRefresh() {
   posts.removeAll()

    loadPost()
  tableView.reloadData()
   self.tableView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue" {
        let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        let postId = sender as! String
        commentVC.postId = postId
    }

    if segue.identifier == "Home_ProfileSegue" {
        let profileVC = segue.destination as! ProfileUserViewController
        let userId = sender as! String
        profileVC.userId = userId
    }

    if segue.identifier == "Home_Hashtag" {
        let hashTagVc = segue.destination as! HashTagViewController
        let tag = sender as! String
        hashTagVc.tag = tag
    }
}



func loadPost() {

    API.Feed.observeFeed(withId: API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid) { (post) in
        guard let postUid = post.userId else {
            return
        }
        self.fetchUser(uid: postUid, completed: {


            self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        API.Post.calculateScore(postId: post.id!, onSuccess: { (post) in


        }) { (errorMessage) in
            ProgressHUD.showError(errorMessage)
        }

    }



    API.Feed.observeFeedRemoved(withId: API.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid) { (post) in

        self.posts = self.posts.filter{ $0.id != post.id }
        self.users = self.users.filter{$0.id != post.userId }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
    API.User.observeUser(withId: uid, completion: {
        user in

        self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
        completed()
    })

}
}



 extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell


    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.post = post
    cell.user = user
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

}

```
extension HomeViewController : HomeTableViewCellDelegate {
func goToCommentViewController(postId:String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommentSegue", sender: postId)
}
func goToProfileUserViewController(userId: String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home_ProfileSegue", sender: userId)
}

func goToHashtag(tag: String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home_Hashtag", sender: tag)
}
func goToLikesViewController(postId:String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "LikeSegue", sender: postId)
}
```

}

That VC is like the feed on Instagram where all the cells are for each post. Each post counts the users who liked it and I would like to show the likes from users who liked the observed post, not the hardcoded post.

Thank you. :)

Comment: I would suggest that you get new access tokens since you just published them for everyone to see. This could give them access to your database and storage.

Comment: @TristanBeaton At first sight I don't see any values that are a security risk. What values are you referring to and what risks do you think it would pose to share those?

Comment: I was under the impression that with the access token people could bypass the user login stage and possibly do damage to your database.

Comment: I just want it to be like in Instagram where you click on the like count button and see everyone who liked the post

Comment: @TristanBeaton do you mean the access token in the `photoUrl` properties? Those values are the so-called download URLs that Firebase generates for Cloud Storage files. Download URLs are publicly readable, but unguessable URLs that you can share if you want to give public read-only access to the file. The accesss tokens are just there to make the URLs unguessable.

Comment: That's fine. It is just that I had watched a firebase tutorial a while ago where this guy said about not sharing access tokens. I was just concerned. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If you provide a link, I can have a look. But there are many types of access tokens, API keys and other identifiers. Some of them are meant to be kept secrets, other (like the access token in the download URLs) are meant to be shared publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with. I tested it using your JSON, and it worked. It might be a bit different from your original code, but it should give you an idea on how to implement it. Also, the fetchUser function seemed useless so I left it out, and the username_lowercase is pointless since you can just call .lowercased() on any String.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LikesViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postId: String! // add this var

    var users = Array<User>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.loadUserLikes()
    }

    func loadUserLikes(){

        let api = UserApi()

        // changed this to var postId
        api.observeUserLikes(withPostId: postId) { (uids) in

            for uid in uids {

                api.observeUser(withId: uid, completion: { (user) in

                    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

                        if uid == currentUser.uid {

                            self.users.insert(user, at: 0) // This will put the current user at the start of the array, so should be at top of table view.

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                            return
                        }
                    }

                    self.users.append(user)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: TableView Delegates
}

struct User {

    var uid: String

    var username: String

    var email: String

    var profileText: String

    var profileImageURL: String

    init?(uid: String, dict: Dictionary<String,String>) {

        guard

            let username = dict["username"],

            let email = dict["email"],

            let profileText = dict["profilText"],

            let profileImageURL = dict["profileImageUrl"]

        else {

            return nil
        }

        self.uid = uid

        self.username = username

        self.email = email

        self.profileText = profileText

        self.profileImageURL = profileImageURL
    }
}

class UserApi {

    var REF_USERS = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    var REF_POST_USERS_LIKED = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("LikesFromUsers")

    var REF_POST = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")

    func observeUser(withId uid: String,  completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {

        REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,String> else { return }

            if let user = User(uid: snapshot.key, dict: dict) {

                completion(user)

            } else {

                print("Incomplete User Data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func observeUsers(completion: @escaping (Array<User>) -> Void) {

        REF_USERS.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>> else { return }

            var users = Array<User>()

            for (key, value) in dict {

                if let user = User(uid: key, dict: value) {

                    guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }

                    if user.uid != currentUser.uid {

                        users.append(user)
                    }

                } else {

                    print("Incomplete User Data.")
                }
            }

            completion(users)
        })
    }

    func observeUserLikes(withPostId id: String , completion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> Void) {

        REF_POST_USERS_LIKED.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Bool> else { return }

            var users = Array<String>() // Array of user ids who liked the post.

            for (key, value) in dict {

                if value == true {

                    users.append(key)
                }
            }

            completion(users)
        })
    }

    // I've added this to get all the posts.
    func observePosts(completion: @escaping (Array<Post>) -> Void) {

        REF_POST.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>> else { return }

            var posts = Array<Post>()

            for (key, value) in dict {

                if let post = Post(uid: key, dict: value) {

                    posts.append(post)

                } else {

                    print("Incomplete Post Data.")
                }
            }

            completion(posts)
        })
    }
}
```

This is the Post View Controller that I have made to test the Likes View Controller.

```
struct Post {

    var uid: String

    var photoUrl: String

    var ratio: Double

    var score: Double

    var creationDate: Date

    init?(uid: String, dict: Dictionary<String,Any>) {

        guard

            let photoUrl = dict["photoUrl"] as? String,

            let ratio = dict["ratio"] as? Double,

            let score = dict["score"] as? Double,

            let creationDate = dict["creationDate"] as? TimeInterval

            else {

                return nil
        }


        self.uid = uid

        self.photoUrl = photoUrl

        self.ratio = ratio

        self.score = score

        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: creationDate)
    }
}

struct Comment {

    var uid: String

    var user: User

    var comment: String
}

class PostsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var posts = Array<Post>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let api = UserApi()

        api.observePosts { (posts) in

            self.posts = posts

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.posts.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = post.uid

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Just for testing, I have it show the likes view controller when the cell is tapped. 
        // Although you will probably have this as a button, so just copy this code into the action.

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LikesViewController") as? LikesViewController else { return }

        vc.postId = post.uid

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

These screenshots only show the uid of the post or user, but you'll be able to change this to show all the required data.

[image: This is the Posts View Controller]

[image: This is the Likes View Controller]

Comment: Okay thank you that really worked ! Now I need to know how I get the users who liked the post from each specific post as it is hardcoded now ? And moreover my app crashes a t the point where it wants to configure the follow button, I commented it out so It worked but thats not ideal

Comment: Are you asking how to have this view controller show the users based on the post that they clicked on? If this is the case, can you add some code of the view controller that all the posts are on?

Comment: Sure I will add it when i am at my pc

Comment: I edited the Post! Moreover I fixed the follow Bug, so its just now how I get the data from the clicked on post instead of the hardcoded Post

Comment: Hey thanks a lot now it is working perfectly fine. But now I have a big error which does not belong to the method we created. When I load my post its now lading like limitlessly often ( I did not change anything) and I get the maxretry error) Do you know how to fix that? Did you have something similar happen to you? As I said I changed nothing but my score function gets called extremely often now until it crashes and the maxRetry error occurs

Comment: Moreover I can see the logged in user and I would like to not show the logged in user or at least hide the Follow bar. I have the function "  if user.id! != API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid {
                    completion(user)

                }" how can I translate it in your methode

Comment: I didn't have any trouble with the code when I tested it and I haven't heard of that max retry error before. For the follow button, in the cellForRowAt indexPath, just set the follow button to hidden if the current user uid is equal to the like user uid.

Comment: Okay thank you, it works :) . That error was just a temporary error with the firebase database, I messaged the support now everything works fine. Do you know how I can say that the currentUser is shown at indexPath 0? so the first is if liked always the current user?

Comment: I've added some code to put the user at the top of the table view.

Comment: Thanks! I had to adjust the code a bit because the user would have been shown twice otherwise. Now it works as expected :)